# custom type define in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, max, typeclass

Im new to haskell, I defined a custom list type.But when I try to define this function mymaximum. I notice that it only works if a is of type Num. what should I change if I want it to work with all types, for example Char?

```
data List a = ListNode a (List a) | ListEnd

mymaximum::List a -> a
mymaximum ListEnd = 0
mymaximum (ListNode x xs) 
    |  x > maxxs = x
    | otherwise = maxxs
    where maxxs = mymaximum xs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you try to load the definition as given you get an error message,

```
....
 No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `0'
 Possible fix:
   add (Num a) to the context of
     the type signature for mymaximum :: List a -> a
....
```

So this suggests you need to change the type signature to

```
mymaximum :: (Num a) => List a -> a
```

*Now* the error message is

```
....
Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of `>'
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for mymaximum :: Num a => List a -> a
  at <interactive>:59:14-35
Possible fix:
  add (Ord a) to the context of
    the type signature for mymaximum :: Num a => List a -> a
....
```

and just the same, we change the type signature to

```
mymaximum :: (Num a, Ord a) => List a -> a
```

and now GHCi responds:

```
mymaximum :: (Num a, Ord a) => List a -> a
```

Meaning, it accepted the definition with its type signature.

Now this fucntion will work with all types that implement both `Num` and `Ord` typeclasses.

`Int` is one, `Float` is another. `Char` is not. But if you `import Data.Char`, you can use the functions

```
chr :: Int -> Char

ord :: Char -> Int
```

to get around this, by mapping `ord` over your `List Char` value (you'll have to also define your own `map` function for that ... perhaps), finding your maximum, then working backwards with `chr` to recover the character.

*update:* as you've noticed, special casing `0` as the maximum value of an empty list is *not* The Right Thing to do. Making a one-element list to be your base case is a good solution for that. Now the `Num a` constraint can be removed and the function will work as is for `List Char` arguments as well, or any `Ord a => List a` type of value, producing an `Ord a => a` type of value as a result.

One caveat though: you still need to handle the empty list case, perhaps by calling `error` with a specific error message, like

```
mymaximum ListEnd = error " mymaximum: empty list is not allowed! "
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try your solution. I just figured out another way to do it. by changing my base case to mymaximum (ListNode x ListEnd) = x and add Ord a to type signiture work as well.

Comment: great! indeed, using `0` was incorrect. On the other hand this means that your function needs to specify separately what to do when it receives `ListEnd` (i.e., an empty list) as an argument. Erroring out with a specific error message is one possibility. Another is changing the output type to `Maybe a` and returning `Nothing` in the empty list case.